# Ubuntu 22.04 on IdeaPad L340-15IRH Gaming - Wired Networking Not Working

Tags: networking, 22.04, ideapad

I've tried both upgrades from 21.04 and 21.10 plus a fresh install on my IdeaPad L340-15IRH Gaming. After both upgrades and fresh installs the wired networking stops working. I will get a valid IP address using DHCP but no connectivity. Manually setting the IP, gateway, etc. does not fix the issue. The only info i get from `dmesg` is:

```
[   65.543786] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   65.543797] NETDEV WATCHDOG: enp7s0 (r8169): transmit queue 0 timed out
[   65.543816] WARNING: CPU: 7 PID: 0 at net/sched/sch_generic.c:477 dev_watchdog+0x273/0x280
[   65.543824] Modules linked in: rfcomm vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock vmw_vmci cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nvidia_uvm(PO) snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation snd_hda_codec_realtek soundwire_cadence nvidia_drm(PO) snd_hda_codec_generic nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp intel_tcc_cooling snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_powerclamp nvidia(PO) mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_soc_acpi i915 soundwire_bus ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine uvcvideo snd_hda_intel snd_seq_midi coretemp snd_intel_dspcfg videobuf2_vmalloc snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core ttm videobuf2_memops btusb snd_rawmidi kvm_intel iwlmvm snd_hwdep videobuf2_v4l2 kvm mac80211 libarc4 snd_seq btrtl snd_pcm btbcm crct10dif_pclmul drm_kms_helper videobuf2_common cec btintel
[   65.543957]  processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_device rc_core bluetooth processor_thermal_device i2c_algo_bit iwlwifi aesni_intel processor_thermal_rfim processor_thermal_mbox videodev processor_thermal_rapl snd_timer fb_sys_fops mei_me intel_rapl_common syscopyarea joydev nls_iso8859_1 crypto_simd cryptd rapl sysfillrect ecdh_generic intel_wmi_thunderbolt wmi_bmof serio_raw intel_cstate efi_pstore ideapad_laptop snd 8250_dw input_leds cfg80211 mc ecc mei sysimgblt soundcore sparse_keymap int3403_thermal intel_pch_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf mac_hid elan_i2c platform_profile int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad acpi_tad sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid r8169 i2c_i801 crc32_pclmul realtek i2c_smbus i2c_hid_acpi intel_lpss_pci nvme ahci i2c_hid xhci_pci intel_lpss nvme_core libahci idma64 xhci_pci_renesas hid
[   65.544123]  wmi video pinctrl_cannonlake
[   65.544129] CPU: 7 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/7 Tainted: P           O      5.15.0-27-generic #28-Ubuntu
[   65.544132] Hardware name: LENOVO 81LK/LNVNB161216, BIOS BGCN34WW 05/21/2021
[   65.544134] RIP: 0010:dev_watchdog+0x273/0x280
[   65.544139] Code: eb 97 48 8b 5d d0 c6 05 5d 15 6e 01 01 48 89 df e8 72 92 f9 ff 44 89 e1 48 89 de 48 c7 c7 c8 02 0d b6 48 89 c2 e8 31 4d 19 00 <0f> 0b eb 80 e9 85 a0 22 00 0f 1f 40 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5
[   65.544141] RSP: 0018:ffffb89e802cce70 EFLAGS: 00010282
[   65.544145] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff983550494000 RCX: 000000000000083f
[   65.544147] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00000000000000f6 RDI: 000000000000083f
[   65.544149] RBP: ffffb89e802ccea8 R08: 0000000000000003 R09: fffffffffffda3d8
[   65.544151] R10: 0000000000ffff0a R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000000000
[   65.544153] R13: ffff983550484e80 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: ffff9835504944c0
[   65.544156] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9836a63c0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[   65.544158] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[   65.544160] CR2: 00007fe522dfa000 CR3: 0000000068410001 CR4: 00000000003706e0
[   65.544163] Call Trace:
[   65.544165]  <IRQ>
[   65.544168]  ? pfifo_fast_enqueue+0x150/0x150
[   65.544172]  call_timer_fn+0x2b/0x120
[   65.544176]  __run_timers.part.0+0x1dd/0x250
[   65.544178]  ? ktime_get+0x46/0xc0
[   65.544182]  ? lapic_next_deadline+0x2c/0x40
[   65.544185]  ? clockevents_program_event+0xa9/0x120
[   65.544190]  run_timer_softirq+0x2a/0x50
[   65.544192]  __do_softirq+0xd9/0x2e3
[   65.544198]  irq_exit_rcu+0x8c/0xb0
[   65.544202]  sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x7c/0x90
[   65.544205]  </IRQ>
[   65.544207]  <TASK>
[   65.544208]  asm_sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x12/0x20
[   65.544212] RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xd9/0x620
[   65.544216] Code: 3d 14 5b be 4a e8 d7 ad 6c ff 49 89 c7 0f 1f 44 00 00 31 ff e8 28 ba 6c ff 80 7d d0 00 0f 85 5d 01 00 00 fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <45> 85 f6 0f 88 69 01 00 00 4d 63 ee 49 83 fd 09 0f 87 e3 03 00 00
[   65.544219] RSP: 0018:ffffb89e80137e28 EFLAGS: 00000246
[   65.544222] RAX: ffff9836a63f0f00 RBX: ffffd89e7fbe3c00 RCX: 0000000000000000
[   65.544224] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000002 RDI: 0000000000000000
[   65.544226] RBP: ffffb89e80137e78 R08: 0000000f42b6bd74 R09: 0000000000000000
[   65.544228] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: fffffffffffffffe R12: ffffffffb6ad3580
[   65.544229] R13: 0000000000000008 R14: 0000000000000008 R15: 0000000f42b6bd74
[   65.544233]  ? cpuidle_enter_state+0xc8/0x620
[   65.544236]  ? tick_nohz_stop_tick+0x166/0x1d0
[   65.544240]  cpuidle_enter+0x2e/0x40
[   65.544243]  cpuidle_idle_call+0x13e/0x1e0
[   65.544246]  do_idle+0x83/0xf0
[   65.544249]  cpu_startup_entry+0x20/0x30
[   65.544252]  start_secondary+0x12a/0x180
[   65.544254]  secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xc2/0xcb
[   65.544259]  </TASK>
[   65.544260] ---[ end trace 4a50d45daa6514bd ]---
[   65.574580] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_chipcmd_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[   65.597480] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[   65.620330] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[   65.641526] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[   65.662543] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[   65.683564] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[   65.704584] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[   65.725596] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[   65.746615] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[   65.767535] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[  187.681080] net_ratelimit: 13 callbacks suppressed
[  187.681091] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_chipcmd_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[  187.704978] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[  187.728212] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[  187.751713] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[  187.775619] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[  187.799547] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[  187.823068] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[  187.846556] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[  187.870094] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[  187.893852] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[  358.386826] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
```

Info from `lspci` is:

```
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

EFI secure boot is enabled.

This

*** EDIT #2 - **pre** and **post** were the same ***
`syslog` info:

```
Apr 30 13:44:35 winchester kernel: [    0.290375] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
Apr 30 13:44:35 winchester kernel: [    0.951821] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: bca3e9340f33faf0c731e54579444bf4d584ec0e'
Apr 30 13:44:35 winchester kernel: [    0.952194] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: a26ac46bad0278bbfecff6972b7d6c4ae5116e30'
Apr 30 13:44:35 winchester kernel: [    0.952377] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: cc9830517009e3c39d8486e54d3dad9b49fc076c'
Apr 30 13:44:35 winchester kernel: [    0.952557] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: 487cddccbfff14c704f494088f63be2279a09cce'
Apr 30 13:44:35 winchester kernel: [    0.953464] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: c23a7e5e24e3a6d8bc7ecf68388d3c08cc7dc044'
Apr 30 13:44:35 winchester kernel: [    4.213438] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
Apr 30 13:51:45 winchester kernel: [    0.293271] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
Apr 30 13:51:45 winchester kernel: [    0.960964] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: bca3e9340f33faf0c731e54579444bf4d584ec0e'
Apr 30 13:51:45 winchester kernel: [    0.961340] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: a26ac46bad0278bbfecff6972b7d6c4ae5116e30'
Apr 30 13:51:45 winchester kernel: [    0.961525] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: cc9830517009e3c39d8486e54d3dad9b49fc076c'
Apr 30 13:51:45 winchester kernel: [    0.961710] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: 487cddccbfff14c704f494088f63be2279a09cce'
Apr 30 13:51:45 winchester kernel: [    0.962628] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: c23a7e5e24e3a6d8bc7ecf68388d3c08cc7dc044'
Apr 30 13:51:45 winchester kernel: [    4.546892] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
Apr 30 16:06:07 winchester kernel: [    0.284583] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
Apr 30 16:06:07 winchester kernel: [    0.794706] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: bca3e9340f33faf0c731e54579444bf4d584ec0e'
Apr 30 16:06:07 winchester kernel: [    0.794933] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: a26ac46bad0278bbfecff6972b7d6c4ae5116e30'
Apr 30 16:06:07 winchester kernel: [    0.795046] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: cc9830517009e3c39d8486e54d3dad9b49fc076c'
Apr 30 16:06:07 winchester kernel: [    0.795155] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: 487cddccbfff14c704f494088f63be2279a09cce'
Apr 30 16:06:07 winchester kernel: [    0.795708] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: c23a7e5e24e3a6d8bc7ecf68388d3c08cc7dc044'
Apr 30 16:06:07 winchester kernel: [    3.963059] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
Apr 30 16:30:17 winchester kernel: [    0.284701] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
Apr 30 16:30:17 winchester kernel: [    0.800901] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: bca3e9340f33faf0c731e54579444bf4d584ec0e'
Apr 30 16:30:17 winchester kernel: [    0.801124] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: a26ac46bad0278bbfecff6972b7d6c4ae5116e30'
Apr 30 16:30:17 winchester kernel: [    0.801231] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: cc9830517009e3c39d8486e54d3dad9b49fc076c'
Apr 30 16:30:17 winchester kernel: [    0.801338] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: 487cddccbfff14c704f494088f63be2279a09cce'
Apr 30 16:30:17 winchester kernel: [    0.801960] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: c23a7e5e24e3a6d8bc7ecf68388d3c08cc7dc044'
Apr 30 16:30:17 winchester kernel: [    4.199612] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
Apr 30 16:43:20 winchester kernel: [    0.284165] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
Apr 30 16:43:20 winchester kernel: [    4.057780] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
Apr 30 16:46:29 winchester kernel: [    0.284018] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
Apr 30 16:46:29 winchester kernel: [    0.794771] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: bca3e9340f33faf0c731e54579444bf4d584ec0e'
Apr 30 16:46:29 winchester kernel: [    0.794996] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: a26ac46bad0278bbfecff6972b7d6c4ae5116e30'
Apr 30 16:46:29 winchester kernel: [    0.795107] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: cc9830517009e3c39d8486e54d3dad9b49fc076c'
Apr 30 16:46:29 winchester kernel: [    0.795216] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: 487cddccbfff14c704f494088f63be2279a09cce'
Apr 30 16:46:29 winchester kernel: [    0.795765] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: c23a7e5e24e3a6d8bc7ecf68388d3c08cc7dc044'
Apr 30 16:46:29 winchester kernel: [    3.880189] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
Apr 30 18:30:49 winchester kernel: [    0.284650] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
Apr 30 18:30:49 winchester kernel: [    0.862635] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: bca3e9340f33faf0c731e54579444bf4d584ec0e'
Apr 30 18:30:49 winchester kernel: [    0.863009] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: a26ac46bad0278bbfecff6972b7d6c4ae5116e30'
Apr 30 18:30:49 winchester kernel: [    0.863191] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: cc9830517009e3c39d8486e54d3dad9b49fc076c'
Apr 30 18:30:49 winchester kernel: [    0.863373] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: 487cddccbfff14c704f494088f63be2279a09cce'
Apr 30 18:30:49 winchester kernel: [    0.864284] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: c23a7e5e24e3a6d8bc7ecf68388d3c08cc7dc044'
Apr 30 18:30:49 winchester kernel: [    4.021937] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
Apr 30 18:36:24 winchester kernel: [    0.283965] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
Apr 30 18:36:24 winchester kernel: [    0.794432] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: bca3e9340f33faf0c731e54579444bf4d584ec0e'
Apr 30 18:36:24 winchester kernel: [    0.794656] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: a26ac46bad0278bbfecff6972b7d6c4ae5116e30'
Apr 30 18:36:24 winchester kernel: [    0.794764] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: cc9830517009e3c39d8486e54d3dad9b49fc076c'
Apr 30 18:36:24 winchester kernel: [    0.794872] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: 487cddccbfff14c704f494088f63be2279a09cce'
Apr 30 18:36:24 winchester kernel: [    0.795419] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: c23a7e5e24e3a6d8bc7ecf68388d3c08cc7dc044'
Apr 30 18:36:24 winchester kernel: [    0.795528] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: 3d3ba0bbc92f8893dcbee30645165d01a2c909d4'
Apr 30 18:36:24 winchester kernel: [    2.509545] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
May  1 11:25:01 winchester kernel: [    0.282958] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
May  1 11:25:01 winchester kernel: [    0.813113] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: bca3e9340f33faf0c731e54579444bf4d584ec0e'
May  1 11:25:01 winchester kernel: [    0.813483] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: a26ac46bad0278bbfecff6972b7d6c4ae5116e30'
May  1 11:25:01 winchester kernel: [    0.813672] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: cc9830517009e3c39d8486e54d3dad9b49fc076c'
May  1 11:25:01 winchester kernel: [    0.813857] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: 487cddccbfff14c704f494088f63be2279a09cce'
May  1 11:25:01 winchester kernel: [    0.814775] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: c23a7e5e24e3a6d8bc7ecf68388d3c08cc7dc044'
May  1 11:25:01 winchester kernel: [    0.814965] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: 3d3ba0bbc92f8893dcbee30645165d01a2c909d4'
May  1 11:25:01 winchester kernel: [    3.943371] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
May  2 16:50:38 winchester kernel: [    0.284617] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
May  2 16:50:38 winchester kernel: [    0.791919] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: bca3e9340f33faf0c731e54579444bf4d584ec0e'
May  2 16:50:38 winchester kernel: [    0.792150] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: a26ac46bad0278bbfecff6972b7d6c4ae5116e30'
May  2 16:50:38 winchester kernel: [    0.792264] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: cc9830517009e3c39d8486e54d3dad9b49fc076c'
May  2 16:50:38 winchester kernel: [    0.792375] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: 487cddccbfff14c704f494088f63be2279a09cce'
May  2 16:50:38 winchester kernel: [    0.792937] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: c23a7e5e24e3a6d8bc7ecf68388d3c08cc7dc044'
May  2 16:50:38 winchester kernel: [    0.793051] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: 3d3ba0bbc92f8893dcbee30645165d01a2c909d4'
May  2 16:50:38 winchester kernel: [    4.103589] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
May  2 17:11:57 winchester kernel: [    0.296136] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
May  2 17:11:57 winchester kernel: [    0.921582] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: bca3e9340f33faf0c731e54579444bf4d584ec0e'
May  2 17:11:57 winchester kernel: [    0.921957] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: a26ac46bad0278bbfecff6972b7d6c4ae5116e30'
May  2 17:11:57 winchester kernel: [    0.922139] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: cc9830517009e3c39d8486e54d3dad9b49fc076c'
May  2 17:11:57 winchester kernel: [    0.922320] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: 487cddccbfff14c704f494088f63be2279a09cce'
May  2 17:11:57 winchester kernel: [    0.923242] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: c23a7e5e24e3a6d8bc7ecf68388d3c08cc7dc044'
May  2 17:11:57 winchester kernel: [    0.923427] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'MSI: 3d3ba0bbc92f8893dcbee30645165d01a2c909d4'
May  2 17:11:57 winchester kernel: [    4.461825] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI`
```

Comment: No guarantees, but try installing **r8168-dkms**, then reboot, retest. Report back. Also, edit your question and show me `grep -i msi /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: @heynnema - installing **r8168-dkms** worked. THANKS! Pre/post info posted in edited question

Comment: FYI... the pre/post info is the same.

Comment: Thanks! I should have `diff`ed them and saved some space :-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

Install **r8168-dkms**, reboot, then retest.

**Update #1:**

*Installing r8168-dkms worked!*