# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS requires frequent restarts of Ethernet

Tags: networking, 22.04, lts

Troubleshooting a system remotely. User describes that occasionally they will have to toggle the Network button in settings on and off like 20 times before it connects to the network. They did not have to do this on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Here is the sudo lshw and the lspci

```
$ sudo lshw -c network
[sudo] password: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 1b
       serial: b0:4f:13:15:4f:35
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-39-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.88 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d1204000-d1204fff memory:d1200000-d1203fff
$ 
$ lspci
.......
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 1b)
.......
```

Followed someone's advice and looked at the NetworkManager logs via:

```
sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager
```

Definitely seems like there's something funky going on (keep in mind this is a different machine, but same issues). If I understand it correctly, you can clearly see the guy toggling it on and off once before it works. There's also one or two thigns that are failing as it's running but I don't know which of them are problematic or not. BTW only enp2s0 is the one with the ethernet plugged in.

```
csplt-hx500@csplthx500-HX500:~$ sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.8597] NetworkManager (version 1.36.6) is starting... (for the first time)
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.8597] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr->
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.8638] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.8765] manager[0x55f917acb040]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.8765] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9628] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9628] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "csplthx500-HX500"
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9643] dns-mgr[0x55f917aa4aa0]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9701] rfkill1: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (drive>
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9702] manager[0x55f917acb040]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set disabled
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9702] manager[0x55f917acb040]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9775] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9787] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9814] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9849] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9879] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9881] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi disabled by radio killswitch; disabled by state file
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9882] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9882] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9922] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdow>
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9923] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9923] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9926] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9963] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9964] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9965] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9973] manager: (enp0s31f6): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Feb 04 11:31:02 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531862.9975] device (enp0s31f6): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Feb 04 11:31:03 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531863.2185] manager: (enp2s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Feb 04 11:31:03 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531863.2187] device (enp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Feb 04 11:31:03 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531863.2457] device (wlp1s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Feb 04 11:31:03 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531863.2460] manager: (wlp1s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Feb 04 11:31:03 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531863.2462] device (wlp1s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Feb 04 11:31:03 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531863.2479] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Feb 04 11:31:03 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531863.2516] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Feb 04 11:31:06 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531866.1627] device (enp2s0): carrier: link connected
Feb 04 11:31:06 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531866.1629] device (enp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 04 11:31:06 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531866.1656] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 2' (f9e7b32b-5b2d-3a0c-893f-0140a8865531)
Feb 04 11:31:06 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531866.1659] device (enp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 2' (f9e7b32b-5b2d-3a0c-893f-0140a8865531)
Feb 04 11:31:06 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531866.1659] device (enp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 04 11:31:06 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531866.1661] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Feb 04 11:31:06 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531866.1661] device (enp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 04 11:31:06 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531866.1670] device (enp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 04 11:31:06 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531866.1701] dhcp4 (enp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 04 11:31:10 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531870.3498] agent-manager: agent[0a65f937a10aa8cc,:1.55/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Feb 04 11:31:10 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531870.4088] dhcp4 (enp2s0): state changed new lease, address=172.16.0.137
Feb 04 11:31:10 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531870.4105] device (enp2s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 04 11:31:10 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531870.4143] device (enp2s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 04 11:31:10 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531870.4145] device (enp2s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 04 11:31:10 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531870.4147] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Feb 04 11:31:10 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531870.4150] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Feb 04 11:31:10 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531870.4150] policy: set 'Wired connection 2' (enp2s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Feb 04 11:31:10 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531870.4155] device (enp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Feb 04 11:31:10 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531870.4159] manager: startup complete
Feb 04 11:31:38 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531898.6010] device (enp2s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'user-requested', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 04 11:31:38 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531898.6015] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTING
Feb 04 11:31:38 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531898.6038] audit: op="device-disconnect" interface="enp2s0" ifindex=2 pid=2117 uid=1000 result="success"
Feb 04 11:31:38 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531898.6239] device (enp2s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'user-requested', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 04 11:31:38 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531898.6613] dhcp4 (enp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Feb 04 11:31:38 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531898.6613] dhcp4 (enp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 04 11:31:38 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531898.6614] dhcp4 (enp2s0): state changed no lease
Feb 04 11:31:38 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531898.6647] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Feb 04 11:31:44 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531904.5027] device (enp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 2' (f9e7b32b-5b2d-3a0c-893f-0140a8865531)
Feb 04 11:31:44 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531904.5030] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="f9e7b32b-5b2d-3a0c-893f-0140a8865531" name="Wired connection 2" pid=2117 uid=1000 re>
Feb 04 11:31:44 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531904.5033] device (enp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 04 11:31:44 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531904.5041] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Feb 04 11:31:44 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531904.5044] device (enp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 04 11:31:44 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531904.5065] device (enp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 04 11:31:44 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531904.5081] dhcp4 (enp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 04 11:31:44 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531904.5290] dhcp4 (enp2s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.193
Feb 04 11:31:44 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531904.5305] device (enp2s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 04 11:31:44 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531904.5316] device (enp2s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 04 11:31:44 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531904.5317] device (enp2s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 04 11:31:44 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531904.5320] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Feb 04 11:31:44 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531904.5323] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Feb 04 11:31:44 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531904.5323] policy: set 'Wired connection 2' (enp2s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Feb 04 11:31:44 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531904.5328] device (enp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Feb 04 11:31:44 csplthx500-HX500 NetworkManager[814]: <info>  [1675531904.7670] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405788/ubuntu-22-04-on-ideapad-l340-15irh-gaming-wired-networking-not-working/1406217#1406217 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Ran the command. Any chance you can assist in the interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly try another network cable and router. Watch the log with `sudo dmesg -w`.

You can also try to disable auto-negotiation - and lower the speed:

```
sudo apt install ethtool
sudo ethtool -s enp3s0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off
```

As a last resort, you can try to switch to the r8168 driver:

```
sudo apt install r8168-dkms
echo "blacklist r8169" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
sudo rmmod r8169; sudo modprobe r8168
```

But usually it's your cable, just not seated properly - remove it and push it back in until you hear the click, on both sides.

Comment: That network cable comment is legit. But seriously actually unplug and replug it in.