# Network Adapter turns off since upgrade to 22.04.1

Tags: networking, drivers, upgrade

I'm using a laptop as a Linux server for a few things. Since the upgrade to 22.04.1, my network card turns off after 45s to 2 min after a reboot. In this time I can SSH into machine or ping google.com. Once the card turns off (Light turns off), I can't ping anything from server and I can't SSH in.

I don't know that the r8169 is the correct driver for my network card. I tried installed r8168 driver, but I'm having issues doing that as well.

Once off, I keep getting the following loops:
[1016.182564] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_chipcmd_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[1016.207481] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_chipcmd_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
[1016.232461] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: rtl_chipcmd_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405788/ubuntu-22-04-on-ideapad-l340-15irh-gaming-wired-networking-not-working) seems identical. Please try the solution provided there and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for the link and response. I stumbled through this on my own by retrying the installation of the ./autorun.sh for my correct driver package. Which I think is what they did over on that link!